# Ayuda sobre String en Java

Tags: java

tengo las siguientes cadenas:

```
String cadena1 = "8 17";
String cadena2 = "25 7";
```

¿Como hago para que en la primera cadena1  obtener el numero 8 primeramente y el numero 17 despues independientemente y la cadena2 obtener el 25 primeramente y el 7 despues? He de decir que ambas cadenas los números están separados por espacios en blanco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la función Split, te guardara en un arreglo cada numero o palabra separada por tal caracter.

```
String[] numeros = string.split(" ");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio